# Lodash, Underscore.js or Lazy.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm working with some large JS objects. So far I've been using lodash for things like finding indexes, sorting, stripping out certain things etc.

All seems to be working fine so far, but I'm wondering if Underscore.js or Lazy.js would be faster for working with big JS objects? Or even native JS for that matter.

Interested to hear peoples thoughts on what the best/fastest library is for working with large objects/arrays.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance issue?

Comment: No, it works beautifully. I'm literally just asking as I'm curious, being the first time I have worked with any of these libraries.

Comment: Nothing will beat native js. Lodash is a "lite" version of underscore

Comment: If thats the case, what is the main purpose of lodash?

Comment: Lodash 3 has lazy evaluation, which are the equivalent of lazy.js sequences - http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/

Comment: @exussum: In fact lodash is a *faster* version of underscore :-)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/native-vs-array-js-vs-underscore/118 I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using lodash, stick with it. Neither lodash, underscore.js, or lazy.js will solve your scalability issues with large objects/arrays by virtue of simply using the library. They definitely help, but they don't remove fundamental constraints (memory, CPU, etc.)

These are just tools, and a minor factor in the scalability of your code. How you leverage these tools to design something that can handle large objects/arrays is the key factor. These designs are unique to the application you're building, and the level of scale (data size) you really need.